# raspberry pi 3 model B and china PN532 not work over SPI

Tags: python, nfc, raspberry-pi3

I switch PN532 over SPI with RPi
( before I tested RPI with rc522 over SPI and module works fine)

Code for reading https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PN532
example/readmifare.py

connection with lines:
for RPi3b

```
RPI         -        PN532

17 3.3v               VCC       
20 Ground             GND       
19 MOSI               MOSI     
21 MISO               MISO      
23 SCLK               SCK      
24 CE0                SS        
26 CE1
```

i change code:

```
#Conf for RPi 3
CS = 24
MOSI = 19
MISO = 21
SCLK = 23
```

## sudo python readmifare.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readmifare.py", line 54, in <module>
    pn532.begin()
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_PN532/examples/PN532.py", line 343, in begin
    self.get_firmware_version()
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_PN532/examples/PN532.py", line 352, in get_firmware_version
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to detect the PN532!  Make sure there is sufficient power (use a 1 amp or greater power supply), the PN532 is wired correctly to the device, and the solder joints on the PN532 headers are solidly connected.')
RuntimeError: Failed to detect the PN532!  Make sure there is sufficient power (use a 1 amp or greater power supply), the PN532 is wired correctly to the device, and the solder joints on the PN532 headers are solidly connected.
```